# Umbraco - MediaPicker Object Data to JSON

Tags: json, xml, umbraco

In Umbraco 7, is it possible to serialize a mediapicker to json? So it could be something like this....

```
[{'name':'muffin', 'file':'muffin.jpg', 'text':'some text', 'etc': 'and so on'}]
```

My setup is like this, I have a mediaPicker named "mediaPhotos". Contained in the folder selected by the mediaPicker I have images of a custom media type "sillyImage".

I can create a controller and query only single items as xml. What I'm trying to target the entire folder of images chosen by the mediapicker and convert its contents to json.

I'm trying to use the solution posted by bowserm below which works like this...

It gets the CurrentPage dynamically with the mediaPicker alias. Then its passed the custom media type.

```
 public class MediaApiController : UmbracoApiController
 {
     [HttpGet]
     public MediaApiModel GetMediaById(string id)
     {
    var media = Umbraco.TypedMedia(id);

    return new MediaApiModel
    {
        MediaId = media.Id,
        MediaUrl = media.Url
    };
}
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<MediaApiModel> GetMediaObj(string mediaAlias)
    {
        var currentPage = Umbraco.TypedContent(UmbracoContext.Current.PageId);
        var mediaRootId = currentPage.GetPropertyValue<string>("mediaPhotos");
        var mediaRoot = Umbraco.TypedMedia(mediaRootId);
        var media = mediaRoot.Children.Where(m => m.IsDocumentType(mediaTypeAlias));
        return media.Select(m => new MediaApiModel
        {
            MediaId = m.Id,
            MediaUrl = m.Url
        });
    }
 }



var uri3 = '//' + document.domain + ':14712' + '/umbraco/api/MediaApi/GetMediaFolder?mediaAlias=sillyImage';
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.getJSON(uri3)
                .done(function (data) {
                    console.log('return json data object ' + data);
                });
        });
```

I'm getting a 500 error now so its getting closer. The issue I think is with these lines in the controller

```
 var currentPage = Umbraco.TypedContent(UmbracoContext.Current.PageId);
        var mediaRootId = currentPage.GetPropertyValue<string>("mediaPhotos");
        var mediaRoot = Umbraco.TypedMedia(mediaRootId);
```

My pages use a page name so PageId I'm not sure is the root issue. The one item I know is that the GetPropertyValue isn't able to get the media picker object from the current page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get your Api Controller to automatically serialize the results to JSON. Just inherit from UmbracoApiController.

```
public class MediaApiController : UmbracoApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public MediaApiModel GetMediaById(string id)
    {
        var media = Umbraco.TypedMedia(id);

        return new MediaApiModel
        {
            MediaId = media.Id,
            MediaUrl = media.Url
        };
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IEnumerable<MediaApiModel> GetMediaObj(string mediaTypeAlias)
    {
        var currentPage = Umbraco.TypedContent(UmbracoContext.Current.PageId);
        var mediaRootId = currentPage.GetPropertyValue<string>("mediaPhotos");
        var mediaRoot = Umbraco.TypedMedia(mediaRootId);
        var media = mediaRoot.Children.Where(m => m.IsDocumentType(mediaTypeAlias));
        return media.Select(m => new MediaApiModel
        {
            MediaId = m.Id,
            MediaUrl = m.Url
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks bowserm, it looks right but I can't figure out the syntax errors



The last line of the return is giving me an error saying it "expects an } or )" and at the close for the return it gives the error "Invalid token ) in class, struck, or interface member declaration"

Comment: Oops. I just edited my answer. The GetMediaObj model should return an IEnumerable of MediaApiModels if you want to get all of them. Also, I had some other syntax errors in there. Try it now.

Comment: I tried out the example above and can't get it to return anything. I'll get a 404 trying to call the "GetMediaObj" method. I know I can hit the controller with the first method "GetMediaById"; which works fine.  I also tried hard coding the custom media type in the alias and still nothing.

Comment: Oops. I just changed the [HttpGet] attribute over the GetMediaObj method into [HttpPost] because you are trying to post in your $.ajax call. Try it now.

Comment: I'm still stuck. I must be missing something else either what I'm posting or how the method is collecting its dependencies.

Comment: The url in your ajax call should start with a leading slash like this: `/Umbraco/Api/MediaApi/GetMediaObj`. Can you verify that you are posting to the correct url?

Comment: I've confirmed there isn't anything amiss with the url. Even the leading slash, that gets automatically added.

Comment: I worked through the 404 issues so now I'm just trying to make sure everything has a value to get the return. I updated back to a GET in the controller so I could simplify my js.